# How to put colon character into xml property powershell, using SetAttribute

Tags: xml, powershell

How do I put a colon character into an XML property Powershell, using `SetAttribute`? Something like this:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated = true
```

Answer (score 4):

You pass the URI for the namespace that corresponds to the "android:" prefix.

If your XML looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

(You really should have provided the XML in your question, by the way, instead of making us look it up.)

Note the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

Then you can set the attribute by passing that URI:

```
$myXml.manifest.application.SetAttribute(
    'hardwareAccelerated', 
    'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android', 
    'true')
```